# Buffer underflow while fetching message from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, trident

I am setting up storm for stream processing, my trident spout is fetching data from kafka topic, but I am getting `BufferUnderFlowException` continuously while fetching messages from kafka:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.fetchMessages(KafkaUtils.java:177) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.fetchMessages(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:132) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaEmitter.doEmitNewPartitionBatch(TridentKafkaEmitter.java:113) ~[stormjar.jar:na]

Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException: null
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:715) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at kafka.api.ApiUtils$.readShortString(ApiUtils.scala:40) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
```

The storm version I am using is 0.9.5 and kafka has version 2.11. I am not able to understand what is creating problem here.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same serializer and deserializer for both message and key in the producer and topology?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisGerken, That really solved my problem :)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to get a similar error if you're using a Kafka client of a different version to your broker.

Comment: did have the same experience

Comment: More recently there was also a bug in kafka that was causing a BufferUnderflowException when fetching consumer group information under some circumstances: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6868

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue for M1 mac.
I tried installing kafka using binaries instead of brew, still the error was there.
Following command didn't work

```
/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic foobar
```

After I replaced localhost with my private ip, it worked.

Find out the ip using

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
```